# Is it possible to have a read-only / shared Equinox environment?

Tags: equinox

I would like to provision a series of OSGi bundles, and then instruct some of them to unpack data into their data area, as obtained with `org.osgi.framework.BundleContext#getDataFile`, and then treat the results as read-only and shared between processes.

Based on some aspects of Eclipse, I suspect this to be possible, but it's not obvious what (if any) configuration properties to set to make it possible.

Comment: Did you investigate [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html). This could be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Setting these properties puts the container into a read-only state:

```
// in spite of the seemingly standard names, these are Equinox-specific.
configProps.put("osgi.configuration.area.readOnly", "true");
configProps.put("osgi.sharedConfiguration.area.readOnly", "true");
configProps.put("osgi.instance.area.readOnly", "true");
configProps.put("osgi.user.area.readOnly", "true");
```